# Show column names together with search results

Tags: javascript, html

Whenever I search for something, I remove the column names to show the results. I would like to show the column names along with the results of my search.

This is the search function I am using:

```js
function searchTable() {
  var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
  input = document.getElementById("search-input");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("table-sort");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    
    for (let j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
      if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        found = true;
      }
    }
    
    if (found) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
      found = false;
    } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="table-sort">
  <tbody id="tBody">
    <tr>
      <th onClick="sortBy(0)">Transaction Date</th>
      <th onClick="sortBy(1)">Merchant</th>
      <th onClick="sortBy(2)">Amount</th>
      <th>Currency</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-th="Transaction Date"> </td>
      <td data-th="Merchant"> </td>
      <td data-th="Amount"> </td>
      <td data-th="Currency"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried adding a function to re-display the column names when a user clicks outside the search input bar (on a div), but this creates an extra column and looks generally messy:

```
    function showCols() {
        tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        for(let i = 0; i < tr.length-1; i++){
            tr[i].style.display = "block"
        }
    };
...
<div id="tablecontainer" onClick="showCols()">
```

Comment: Your first row `tr[0]` should always be visible, right? What if your loop starts at `i=1` instead of `i=0`? You could also put your header row in a `<thead>`, which is a much better way to structure heading/body in a table. If you put your heading in `<thead>`, you can target _only_ your `<tbody>` rows for potential hiding.

Comment: Please revise the demo above to show the problem.

Comment: Protips: `forEach()` is much cleaner and more modern than clumsy `for()` loops with manual incrementation. Also, use `let` and `const` instead of `var` for more clear scoping.